How to work with IF/IFS/ISBLANK when columns contains zero length strings
I process data in excel, where the majority of my data is processed with dynamic functions. Some of the cells appear empty but probably contain a zero length string. In any case, find that EXCEL does not consider the empty cells as actual blanks.  Must make an IFS function, as shown in the attached picture, where the diameter appears. If no calculations have been performed, the database diameter must be used, otherwise the model diameter must be used. But if a diameter is entered manually, then this is the one used. But the challenge is that the "blank" cells in column BJ are not actually blank, which is why my IFS function copies the "blank value" rather than jumping to column BI (the database value).
For the purpose of Quality check of the workbook, I am not allowed to use VBA.
I am using the following function:
=IFS(BK6:BK12>0; BK6:BK12; BJ6:BJ12>0; BJ6:BJ12; BI6:BI12>0; BI6:BI12; ISBLANK(BJ6:BJ12); BI6:BI12)

But I have also tried this function:
=IFS(BK6:BK12>0; BK6:BK12; BJ6:BJ12>0; BJ6:BJ12; BI6:BI12>0; BI6:BI12; BJ6:BJ12=""; BI6:BI12)

And this:
=IFS(BK6:BK12>0; BK6:BK12; BJ6:BJ12>0; BJ6:BJ12; BI6:BI12>0; BI6:BI12; COUNTBLANK(BJ6:BJ12); BI6:BI12)

And this:
=IFS(BK6:BK12>0; BK6:BK12;      BJ6:BJ12>0; BJ6:BJ12;      BI6:BI12>0; BI6:BI12;      BJ6:BJ12<>""; BJ6:BJ12;      ISTEXT(BJ6:BJ12); BI6:BI12;      TRUE; "")

I have also tried to use a nested IF statement instead:
=IF(BK6:BK12>0; BK6:BK12;IF(BJ6:BJ12>0; BJ6:BJ12; BI6:BI12))

This shows how it looks with the function (The wrong answer)

This is how it should look (Correct answer):


If ever I need to check a cell being empty, I just check if the length is larger than zero.

Here is one possible way to parse the blank cells aka not actually blanks.


=IF(1-ISERR(1/BK6#),BK6#,IF(1-ISERR(1/BJ6#),BJ6#,BI6#))


And this is what you might be using for your suit:
=IF(1-ISERR(1/BK6:BK12),BK6:BK12,IF(1-ISERR(1/BJ6:BJ12),BJ6:BJ12,BI6:BI12))


Note: The cells or ranges BI6 , BJ6 and BK6 have the following arrays:
={0.238;0.238;0.396;0.652;0.55;0.396;0.151}


={"";"";0;"";"";0.9;0}


={1;1;"";"";"";0;""}



Yet Another choice:
=BYROW(BI6:BK12,LAMBDA(a,INDEX(a,XMATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1/a),0,-1))))


Or the XLOOKUP version:
=BYROW(BI6:BK12,LAMBDA(a,XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1/a),a,,0,-1)))


Your formula is good only need to convert values to a number like this:
=IF(N(BK6:BK12)>0; BK6:BK12;IF(N(BJ6:BJ12)>0; BJ6:BJ12; BI6:BI12))
